# How do I create a sum based on a selection from a Dropdown box?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to work out a sum based on a selection from a Dropdown box.
If the selection from the Dropdown is chosen and a figure is entered into a separate cell then an answer to a sum is then displayed in a separate cell. I think it is more straight forward than I am making it to be.

If I chose a company in C5, enter a figure in E5 then I would like a result to appear in G5 & H5 based on the loan amount multiplied by the relevant figure.

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: This does seem simple. G5 and H5 just need formulas. Based on the info presented, we have no idea what those would be tho.

Answer (score 0):

If your Dropdown Box is in C5, the Loan in E5 and your Array (Lender Gross  Net) in J,K,L J2:L30 for example, write in 
G5:   `=IF(AND(ISBLANK(C5),ISBLANK(E5)),"",E5*IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C5,$J$2:$L$30,2)),0,VLOOKUP(C5,$J$2:$L$30,2)))`
and in H5:   `=IF(AND(ISBLANK(C5),ISBLANK(E5)),"",E5*IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C5,$J$2:$L$30,3)),0,VLOOKUP(C5,$J$2:$L$30,3)))`
Where `E5*IF()` is your Formula (I looked for the corresponding value of Gross and Net for a given company in C5

Answer (score 0):

If your Lender data validation list in C5 is =$J$4:$J$31 as per your example

for loan amount in E5

The Gross Proc formula in G5 would be

```
=IFERROR(E5*VLOOKUP(C5,J4:L31,2,FALSE),"")
```

and the Net Proc formula in G5 would be

```
=IFERROR(E5*VLOOKUP(C5,J4:L31,3,FALSE),"")
```